# CUDA 5.0 - cudaGetDeviceProperties strange grid size or a bug in my code?

Tags: cuda

I [already posted my question on NVIDIA dev forums](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/546245/cuda-programming-and-performance/cuda-5-0-cudagetdeviceproperties-returns-very-strange-grid-size/), but there are no definitive answers yet.

I'm just starting to learn CUDA and was really surprised that, contrary to what I found on the Internet, my card (GeForce GTX 660M) supports some insane grid sizes (**2147483647** x 65535 x 65535). Please take a look at the following results I'm getting from deviceQuery.exe provided with the toolkit:

```
c:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\bin\win64\Release>deviceQuery.exe
deviceQuery.exe Starting...

CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 660M"
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version 5.5 / 5.0
CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number: 3.0
Total amount of global memory: 2048 MBytes (2147287040 bytes)
( 2) Multiprocessors x (192) CUDA Cores/MP: 384 CUDA Cores
GPU Clock rate: 950 MHz (0.95 GHz)
Memory Clock rate: 2500 Mhz
Memory Bus Width: 128-bit
L2 Cache Size: 262144 bytes
Max Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z) 1D=(65536), 2D=(65536,65536), 3D=(4096,4096,4096)
Max Layered Texture Size (dim) x layers 1D=(16384) x 2048, 2D=(16384,16384) x 2048
Total amount of constant memory: 65536 bytes
Total amount of shared memory per block: 49152 bytes
Total number of registers available per block: 65536
Warp size: 32
Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor: 2048
Maximum number of threads per block: 1024
Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block: 1024 x 1024 x 64
Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid: 2147483647 x 65535 x 65535
Maximum memory pitch: 2147483647 bytes
Texture alignment: 512 bytes
Concurrent copy and kernel execution: Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
Run time limit on kernels: Yes
Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory: No
Support host page-locked memory mapping: Yes
Alignment requirement for Surfaces: Yes
Device has ECC support: Disabled
CUDA Device Driver Mode (TCC or WDDM): WDDM (Windows Display Driver Model)
Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA): Yes
Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID: 1 / 0
Compute Mode:
< Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 5.5, CUDA Runtime Version = 5.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GTX 660M
```

I was curious enough to write a simple program testing if it's possible to use more than 65535 blocks in the first dimension of the grid, but it doesn't work confirming what I found on the Internet (or, to be more precise, does work fine for 65535 blocks and doesn't for 65536).

My program is extremely simple and basically just adds two vectors. This is the source code:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "cudart") 

typedef struct 
{
    float *content;
    const unsigned int size;
} pjVector_t;

__global__ void AddVectorsKernel(float *firstVector, float *secondVector, float *resultVector)
{
    unsigned int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    resultVector[index] = firstVector[index] + secondVector[index];
}

int main(void)
{
    //const unsigned int vectorLength = 67107840; // 1024 * 65535 - works fine
    const unsigned int vectorLength = 67108864; // 1024 * 65536 - doesn't work
    const unsigned int vectorSize = sizeof(float) * vectorLength;
    int threads = 0;
    unsigned int blocks = 0;
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProperties;
    cudaError_t error;

    pjVector_t firstVector = { (float *)calloc(vectorLength, sizeof(float)), vectorLength };
    pjVector_t secondVector = { (float *)calloc(vectorLength, sizeof(float)), vectorLength };
    pjVector_t resultVector = { (float *)calloc(vectorLength, sizeof(float)), vectorLength };

    float *d_firstVector;
    float *d_secondVector;
    float *d_resultVector;

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_firstVector, vectorSize);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_secondVector, vectorSize);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_resultVector, vectorSize);

    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProperties, 0);

    threads = deviceProperties.maxThreadsPerBlock;
    blocks = (unsigned int)ceil(vectorLength / (double)threads);    

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vectorLength; i++)
    {
        firstVector.content[i] = 1.0f;
        secondVector.content[i] = 2.0f;
    }

    cudaMemcpy(d_firstVector, firstVector.content, vectorSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_secondVector, secondVector.content, vectorSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    AddVectorsKernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(d_firstVector, d_secondVector, d_resultVector);
    error = cudaPeekAtLastError();
    cudaMemcpy(resultVector.content, d_resultVector, vectorSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vectorLength; i++)
    {
        if(resultVector.content[i] != 3.0f)
        {
            free(firstVector.content);
            free(secondVector.content);
            free(resultVector.content);

            cudaFree(d_firstVector);
            cudaFree(d_secondVector);
            cudaFree(d_resultVector);
            cudaDeviceReset();

            printf("Error under index: %i\n", i);

            return 0;
        }
    }

    free(firstVector.content);
    free(secondVector.content);
    free(resultVector.content);

    cudaFree(d_firstVector);
    cudaFree(d_secondVector);
    cudaFree(d_resultVector);
    cudaDeviceReset();

    printf("Everything ok!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it from Visual Studio in debug mode (the bigger vector), the last cudaMemcpy always fills my resultVector with seemingly random data (very close to 0 if it matters) so that the result doesn't pass the final validation. When I try to profile it with Visual Profiler, it returns following error message:

*2 events, 0 metrics and 0 source-level metrics were not associated with the kernels and will not be displayed*

As a result, profiler measures only **cudaMalloc** and **cudaMemcpy** operations and doesn't even show the kernel execution.

I'm not sure if I'm checking cuda erros right, so please let me know if it can be done better. **cudaPeekAtLastError()** placed just after my kernel launch returns **cudaErrorInvalidValue(11)** error when the bigger vector is used and **cudaSuccess(0)** for every other call (**cudaMalloc** and **cudaMemcpy**). When I run my program with the smaller vector, all cuda functions and my kernel launch return no errors (**cudaSuccess(0)**) and it works just fine.

So my question is: is cudaGetDeviceProperties returning rubbish grid size values or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What architecture are you compiling this for?

Comment: No, what *gpu* architecture. If you are not explicitly compiling for `sm_30` the code you run will be limited to the grid size dimensions of the default architecture (compute 1.0) which is only 65535 in the first dimension.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that, thanks! I'll check it as sonn as I can (probably during my lunch break) and will let you know if that was it.

Comment: @talonmies That was exactly it. I didn't change the default code generation flags. It works like a charm now since I changed compute_10,sm_10 to compute_30,sm_30. Interesting thing though: according to CUDA wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA), compute capability 1.0 only allows 512 threads per block and I was able to create 1024. Have I missed something?

Comment: I will add my comment as an answer if you would care to accept it so the question is marked as answered. I am not sure why the threads per block worked when the grid size didn't. In theory the JIT recompilation from the driver enforces the execution limitations of the source architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run a kernel using the larger grid size support offered by the Kepler architecture, you must compile you code for that architecture. So change you build flags to sepcific `sm_30` as the target architecture. Otherwise the compiler will build for compute 1.0 targets.

The underlying reason for the launch failure is that the driver will attempt to recompile the compute 1.0 code for your Kepler card, but in doing so it enforces the execution grid limits dictated by the source architecture, ie. two dimensional grids with 65535 x 65535 maximum blocks per grid.